# How to remove event listener from all <tds> when the game is over in battleship?

Tags: javascript

So I've been working on a battleship game, but I've run into a problem which I haven't been able to resolve. When all 8 ships has been found, I want to alert a winning message, total number of shots fired before the player won. Then I want to remove the ability to further click on the tds that represent the squares, thus simulating a "game over". The code below only stops the alerts from showing more than once, but you are still able to click the squares so that it executes some other code. This I want to get rid of. How do I select ALL of the td elements and make all code attached to the click event stop working? Perhaps there is an even easier way to create a "game over" than this? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT** Here's a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pfb8dc83/1/

```
if (hitsCounter == 8) {
    alert('Congratulations! You sank all battleships!');
    alert('You fired ' + totalShots + ' rounds before you won the battle of the sea.');
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0].getElementsByTagName('td');
    all.length.removeEventListener('click', play); //getting an error here saying it's not a function, because of the .length probably. 
}
```

Comment: Why not just put one listener on the table? Search for [*event delegation*](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=javascript+event+delegation&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8&gfe_rd=cr&ei=ymYmVPjFJKuN8Qfe94HABg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding event listeners to each `td` is pretty bad practice, imho.

Try to slightly change your code to attach only one event listener to table body, and change `click` callback to find out `event.target`, it's would be your `td`.

It's will make your code faster and you would be able to remove listener from all td's by removing it from `table`.

Here is your code slightly changed

http://jsfiddle.net/bd07hy5g/1/

Comment: That actually solved 2 of my problems, thank you so much! Can you just explain what the event in play(event) actually does? Does it mean like, cell is equal to the targetted cell of the play function?

Comment: Well, event is the way browser notify all parent elements that something happens. When you click somewhere inside `table` (our case) table is _see_ that and trigger callback that receives `event` object with all required information about what happens as first argument. You can find more technical info at MDN here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event (i'm personally recommend this resource).